# Preventing inapropriate rows from being inserted into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, data-integrity

I have a table for tent rents with the following columns:

```
RentID, DateStarted, DateEnded, CustomerID, etc.
```

`DateStarted` is always entered at the beginning of the rental period, `DateEnded` is initally NULL and only gets filled when the rental period expires. `CustomerID` is the ID of the customer who rented the tent.

What I need to do is prevent users from inserting new rows for any given customer (denoted by `CustomerID`) if that customer has any rents with `DateEnded=NULL`.

I don't know how to do this. I was thinking of a Check constraint, but they don't allow me to see other rows. I was thinking of Unique constraints, but don't know if they could be used in this case. I was thinking of On-Insert trigger, but I'm not sure if I can cancel the insert if the condition is not met.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't know what limits are applied to the SQL Server syntax for a CHECK, but in SQLite its an expression, which means virtually anything you can query for, you can CHECK for. (BTW, where's a good resource for a SQL Server syntax tree?)

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2008.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix ON Rents(CustomerID) WHERE DateEnded IS NULL
```

Earlier Versions you can use an indexed view (For this option various `SET` options need to be configured correctly for connections that update the base table but in SQL Server 2005 they probably will be already.)

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ConstrainRents
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT CustomerID
FROM dbo.Rents 
WHERE DateEnded IS NULL

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix ON dbo.ConstrainRents(CustomerID)
```

Comment: I was thinking about something similar, but then it occurred to me that you could insert a row with `DateEnded` filled and circumvent the rule.

Comment: @Andriy - If that was really a concern the OP could remove insert permissions on the base table and provide a View that has insert permissions but doesn't contain the `DateEnded` column.

Comment: Wow, that's a nice scheme! And you seem to have come up with it so effortlessly. You must have had a rather nourishing meal just lately. :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm on SQL Server 2008, so the first solution should work. I haven't been able to get it to work just yet due to some invalid data in the database, but I'm sure that it's just what we need :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you describe sounds a bit more on the side of your application logic.  I would think that when you think about your database, and what "rules" you want to enforce, think of what would make the data record wrong.  From what you describe, a record with a null DateEnded is a valid record.

From my experience triggers are wonderful if you really need them, but are very dangerous, and very quickly increase the complexity of a problem exponentially.

I would personally avoid a trigger if I can, and do that logic on my application side.

Just my 2 cents

Comment: But you should **still** enforce it in the database as a last line of defence. It doesn't need a trigger at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a look at MS's `instead of` triggers.  Documentation here...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521.aspx

You could also use a `rollback transaction` in a traditional insert trigger.